# What is the distribution of the reciprocal of uniformly distributed random variables?

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

Suppose that $Y_n$ are random variables that are uniformly distributed in the range $[0,1]$, then I know that $P(Y\le y) = \frac{y-a}{b-a}$. What is the distribution of reciprocal $Z_n = \frac{1}{Y_n}$?

Comment: $P(1/Y \leq r)=P(Y \geq 1/r)=\dots$.

Answer (score 7):

The cumulative distribution function for $Z=\frac{1}{Y}$ is
$$P(Z\leq z) = P(Y \geq 1/z) =1-P(Y < 1/z)= 1-\frac{1}{z}$$
for $z \geq 1$.

The probability distribution function is the derivative of this function:
$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}$$
for $z\geq 1$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this so clearly. It makes complete sense to me now.

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations!  You have discovered a Pareto distribution.   The answer above from Natha is correct, but there are a few things about this beastie that remain unsaid.   For example, the mean and variance (and higher moments) do not exist.  Since the central limit theorem relies on a finite variance, a lot of ordinary statistical practice is not applicable.  Order statistics using quartile points and median are OK. Practitioners call this a "tail heavy distribution".

Play with it in a spreadsheet!  Plot the cumulative average for a few hundred.  You will see the average start to converge to a value, then jump wildly to a different value (because the uniform random number generator gave a value near zero).  Very different from the uniform, normal, chisquare, or other distributions we study in college statistics.

Comment: Under the convention of Wikipedia on 'Pareto distribution', this is **Pareto Type I** with $\alpha = 1.$ For $\alpha > 1,$ the mean exists; for $\alpha > 2,$ the variance exists. This family of distributions is $Y = 1/U^{1/\alpha},$ for $U \sim Unif(0,1).$